# Need to remote debug a DLL with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

Is it possible to debug with Visual Studio debugger on a PC without any Visual Studio installation ?

Here's the context :

I'm currently working in a VB project under VS2015 IDE. This project generates a DLL used by two computers :

- Development computer : A test app (written in VB) opens the DLL and I'm debugging this DLL with Visual Studio Debugger ;
- Production computer : An extern app opens the DLL and runs it, but Visual Studio is not installed in this computer and I may not install anything such as remote debugging tools.

A bug appeared in the production computer, but I can't redo it into my dev computer. Unfortunately, I need to get debug info whereas I run the DLL into the prod computer because the bug is not easy to find.

Can someone tell me how to get debug info with a computer that does not have Visual Studio installed on, or to remote debugging it ?

Any information, link or tutorial would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Vick91

Comment: Either save a dump file, or use remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what version of VS you have installed, the best I can give you is this MS article on Remote Debugging:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I've edited the Visual Studio version. Unfortunately I couldn't install remote debugging tools as suggested in the article you provided.

Comment: Instead of installing you can just copy the whole from, for example for x86, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86

Comment: Not only do you not have to install it, you don't even have to copy it to the hard disk; you can just run it from a flash drive or whatever. But that still requires you to have physical access to the remote machine. If that's not the case, do as I suggested above and save a dump file, which you can then open in your own copy of Visual Studio on your development machine and debug it.

Comment: @CodyGray : Thanks for your suggestions. I tried to save a dump file, opened it on my dev computer in Managed Mode and I was able to debug it ! And the fact I can use Remote Debugger from a flash drive is good to know.

Comment: @stijn : Thanks for your suggestion !